# MinGW Compiler Denying Access To Files?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, compiler-errors, mingw, raytracing

I've recently been trying to make a RayTracer however I seem to be falling at the first hurdle.
I have installed VS Code and MinGW, MinGW is set up fine and version is confirmed in console, however, I seem to be running into the same problems over and over and can't seem to get around them :'(

```
cd "s:\Test\" && g++ tempCodeRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "s:\Test\"tempCodeRunnerFile
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/8.2.0/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file tempCodeRunnerFile.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

```
cd "s:\Test\" && g++ test.cpp -o test && "s:\Test\"test
Access is denied.
```

Any help or advice would be much appreciated <3

Comment: Usually this means the .exe is already running (check task manager). Another possibility is if you earlier ran the compiler as a different user and so you now actually don't have permission to write the executable as it is owned by the other user. Or perhaps you don't have write permission for the directory

Comment: There is only one user on this computer and it has only been run on that account